# MDX: Except that i need to total sales amount in particular year

Tags: ssas, mdx

--Total FEB-2008 SalesAmount

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0,
{[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[2]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works] 
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
```

--$47,868.54 (For FEB month 29th SalesAmount)

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0,
{[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080229]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works] 
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
```

--Here how to exclude the FEB month 29th SalesAmount in that Particular Year

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0, 
 EXCEPT(

    [Date].[Calendar].[Month],
    {[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080229]} 
  )
  ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works] 
WHERE [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works] 
WHERE 
  EXCEPT(
    DESCENDANTS(
      [Date].[Calendar].[Year].&[2008],
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date]
    ),
   [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080229]
  );
```

Or this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER  [Date].[Calendar].[All].[2008minus29feb] AS
AGGREGATE(
  EXCEPT(
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS,
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080229]} 
  )
)
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
  [Date].[Calendar].[All].[2008minus29feb] ON 1 
FROM
  (
  SELECT [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2008]  ON 0
  FROM [Adventure Works] 
  );
```

This does it:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    Except
    (
      Descendants
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2008]
       ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
      )
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080229]
    ) ON 0
  FROM [Adventure Works]
);
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replied, but the result is not matched, Could you please see the attached Screen Shot.

Comment: @Yugandhar ok - screenshot is great I now understand the requirements

Comment: @Yugandhar - using a subselect we can do it - see my edit